# How to check in Asp.Net MVC controller's action if user is logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

It is easy to find out in the view but is there any way to get users Name in the index controller?

I have my index action and based on whether user loged in I want the login to be passed a sparameter to my index action like so:

```
 public ActionResult Index(userName)
    {

        var topTenList = repository.FindAllTopTen(userName).ToList();
        var currentList = repository.FindAllCurrentFav(userName).ToList();
        var genreListTemp = repository.FindAllGenres(userName).ToList();
        var userListTemp = repository.FindAllUsers().ToList();


        return View(new HomeViewModel() 
        { 
            topTenFavList = topTenList,
            currentFavList = currentList,
            genreList = genreListTemp,
            userList = userListTemp

        });
    }
```

Comment: What membership provider / method you use? If you are using the aspnet membershipProvider, you just need to [Authorize] your method, and to get username, simply use User.Identity.Name

Comment: yes im using the default asp.net membership but i need to pass the username as a parameter to the index action, so i can query the right model to pass it to my views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to pass it in if they're authenticated:

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

{

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;

var topTenList = repository.FindAllTopTen(userName).ToList();
var currentList = repository.FindAllCurrentFav(userName).ToList();
var genreListTemp = repository.FindAllGenres(userName).ToList();
var userListTemp = repository.FindAllUsers().ToList();


return View(new HomeViewModel() 
{ 
    topTenFavList = topTenList,
    currentFavList = currentList,
    genreList = genreListTemp,
    userList = userListTemp

});
```

}

Comment: thanks, intellisense didnt show me any hints that i could use such code in the controller, but this is what i needed